# Why is xinetd ignoring 'bind' option?

Tags: xinetd

On a server with proftpd controlled by xinetd (plesk/centos FWIW), I want to make proftpd listen only on a specific ip address.

I've tried putting `bind = 12.34.56.78` in `/etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa`, and also putting `DefaultAddress 12.34.56.78` in `/etc/proftpd.conf`, but it seems not to work.

After I restart xinetd, nmap shows that port 21 is still being listened on for my other public ip.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Just as a test I commented out the whole ftp service in the xinetd config file and that did disable the service, so I'm clearly in the right place, but the `bind` options seems not to work.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**: config files (munis comments for brevity)

/etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa

```
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST AFTER YOU UPGRADE PARALLELS PLESK PANEL.

service ftp
{
    flags       = IPv6
        disable     = no
    socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        server          = /usr/sbin/in.proftpd
        server_args     = -c /etc/proftpd.conf
        bind            = 12.34.56.78
}
```

I know it says here not to modify, but I haven't done a plesk upgrade, and I've also tried putting the bind in the defaults section (which has no such warning):

/etc/xinetd.conf

```
defaults
{
    log_type    = SYSLOG daemon info
    log_on_failure  = HOST
    log_on_success  = PID HOST DURATION EXIT
    cps     = 50 10
    instances   = 50
    per_source  = 10
    v6only      = no
    groups      = yes
    umask       = 002
    bind            = 12.34.56.78
}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

And for completeness: /etc/proftpd.conf

```
ServerIdent off
ServerName          "ProFTPD"
ServerType          inetd
DefaultServer           on
<Global>
DefaultRoot ~       psacln
AllowOverwrite      on
</Global>
DefaultTransferMode binary
UseFtpUsers         on
TimesGMT            off
SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime
Port                21
DefaultAddress      12.34.56.78
SocketBindTight     on
Umask               022
MaxInstances            30
ScoreboardFile /var/run/proftpd/scoreboard
TransferLog /usr/local/psa/var/log/xferlog
<Directory /var/www/vhosts>
    GroupOwner  psacln
</Directory>
AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig proftpd
IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off
AuthGroupFile   /etc/group
```

Comment: Could share the full `ftp_psa` fle with us?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen: I've updated the question.

Comment: What process is listening on port 21? Is it xinetd? (Double check with `lsof` or `fuser` or something like that.)

Comment: Yes it is xinetd (according to lsof).

Answer (score 0):

What version of CentOS are you using? I just tried CentOS 6.3. The xinetd-file is called `/etc/xinetd.d/xproftpd`, needs to be enabled with setting `disable=no` in the file and by saying `chkconfig proftpd on`. I only need to set `bind = 10.0.2.15` to let proftpd listen only to this address. No need to tune `proftpd.conf` any further.

After changing `bind` to a distinct value, I wasn't able to connect to any other IP-address any more. Not even `localhost`.

/etc/xinetd.d/xproftpd:

```
# default: off
# description: The ProFTPD FTP server serves FTP connections. It uses \
#   normal, unencrypted usernames and passwords for authentication.
service ftp
{
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.proftpd
    log_on_success      += DURATION USERID
    log_on_failure      += USERID
    nice            = 10
    disable         = no
    bind            = 10.0.2.15
}
```

chkconfig:

```
# chkconfig --list proftpd
proftpd         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

`/etc/proftpd.conf` is still at it's defaults, except setting `ServerType inetd` to make it work with xinetd.

Comment: I'm using CentOS 5.3. `chkconfig` doesn't seem to know about proftpd. My uneducated guess is that its a problem caused by plesk. Sometimes it seems like most of my problems are caused by plesk.